# Timed Selection Between AC Power Sources

Tags: ac, timer

I would like to be able to run a freezer from AC power line A in the daytime and AC power line B at night. Right now, I am manually unplugging the freezer from power line A and plugging it into power line B (and back in the eve). I would like to have this happen via a timer.

Seems like such a simple thing, but I don't see a simple way to do it.

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

K1 is a Double-Pole Double-Throw relay/contactor with a coil rated for your AC mains and contacts rated to supply whatever your freezer needs from the mains, and the [timer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006LYHED0) - for example - is a 24 hour timer which can run off your mains and  be programmed to switch the mains to the relay coil in a never ending  cycle of 12 hours on and 12 hours off.

[image]

Comment: This *can* work but watch out for arcing between the contacts as the relay is switching state.  Personally, I'd use a pair of interlocked contactors so that there is no possibility of arcing between the incoming power lines.

Comment: @Dwayne Reid: Your use of "can" instead of "will" implies that there are conditional issues which could keep the circuit from functioning as intended. Can you list them, please, and what do you see as the mechanism which will cause arcing between the power lines?

Comment: Yes - use a contactor that has both normally-open and normally-closed contacts rather than using a simple relay.  Although these are very similar electrically, the contactor has both much larger gaps between the contacts *and* is designed to quench the arc that occurs when switching an inductive load.

Comment: One of the products that I occasionally build is a switching system that moves the input of large UPSs from one power line to another.  Because the contactors that were readily available to me didn't have normally-closed contacts, I used a pair of normally-open contactors ganged together with a mechanical interlock so that under no circumstances could both contactors pull in at the same time.  I also added NC contact blocks to each contactor for an electrical interlock - if one contactor is pulled-in, the coil for the other is electrically disconnected.  No problem getting certification.